# Optimizing mathematical formula implementation with concatenations of summations

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, optimization, factorial

I'm trying to implement this following formula in Python. It's basically a long concatenation os summations, where an additional summation is added each time a new 'element' is needed. To simply explain the formula's structure, here's how this formula goes in order from 2 to 5 elements:

[2 elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMZ5i.png)

[3 elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3vV7.png)

[4 elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvreM.png)

[5 elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfQep.png)

By the way, here's the *g* function shown in the formulas:

[g function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNbgU.png)

Now, I foolishly tried coding this formula with my extremely barebones python programming skills. The initial goal was to try this with 15 elements, but given that it contained a lot of nested for loops and factorials, I quickly noticed that I could not really obtain a result from that.
At the end I ended up with this monstrous code, that would finish just after the heat death of the universe:

```
from ast import Str
import math

pNuevos = [0,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,1]
pTotales = [0,10,10,7,8,7,7,7,7,7,10,7,8,7,8,8]

def PTirada (personajes):
    tirada = 0.05/personajes
    return tirada

def Ppers1 (personajes, intentos):
    p1pers = ((math.factorial(intentos-1)) / ((math.factorial(4))*(math.factorial(intentos-5)))) * (PTirada(personajes)**5) * ((1-PTirada(personajes))**(intentos-5))
    return p1pers

def Ppers2 (personajes, intentos):
    p2pers = 0
    for i in range(10,intentos+1):
        p2pers = p2pers + ( (math.factorial(intentos-1)) / ((math.factorial(4))*(math.factorial(i-5))*(math.factorial(intentos-i))) ) * (PTirada(personajes)**i) * ((1 - 2*(PTirada(personajes))) **(intentos-i))
    p2pers = 2*p2pers
    return p2pers

def Activate (z) :
    probability1 = 0
    probability2 = 0
    probability3 = 0
    probability4 = 0
    probability5 = 0
    probability6 = 0
    probability7 = 0
    probability8 = 0
    probability9 = 0
    probability10 = 0
    probability11 = 0
    probability12 = 0
    probability13 = 0
    probability14 = 0
    for i in range (5*pNuevos[1], z-5*pNuevos[2]+1):
        for j in range (5*pNuevos[2], z-i-5*pNuevos[3]+1):
            for k in range (5*pNuevos[3], z-j-i-5*pNuevos[4]+1):
                for l in range (5*pNuevos[4], z-k-j-i-5*pNuevos[5]+1):
                    for m in range (5*pNuevos[5], z-l-k-j-i-5*pNuevos[6]+1):
                        for n in range (5*pNuevos[6], z-m-l-k-j-i-5*pNuevos[7]+1):

                            for o in range (5*pNuevos[7], z-n-m-l-k-j-i-5*pNuevos[8]+1):
                                for p in range (5*pNuevos[8], z-o-n-m-l-k-j-i-5*pNuevos[9]+1):
                                    for q in range (5*pNuevos[9], z-p-o-n-m-l-k-j-i-5*pNuevos[10]+1):

                                        for r in range (5*pNuevos[10], z-q-p-o-n-m-l-k-j-i-5*pNuevos[11]+1):
                                            for s in range (5*pNuevos[11], z-r-q-p-o-n-m-l-k-j-i-5*pNuevos[12]+1):
                                                for t in range (5*pNuevos[12], z-s-r-q-p-o-n-m-l-k-j-i-5*pNuevos[13]+1):

                                                    for u in range (5*pNuevos[13], z-t-s-r-q-p-o-n-m-l-k-j-i-5*pNuevos[14]+1):
                                                        for v in range (5*pNuevos[14], z-u-t-s-r-q-p-o-n-m-l-k-j-i-5*pNuevos[15]+1):
                                                            probability14 = probability14 + eval("Ppers"+str(pNuevos[14])+"("+str(pTotales[14])+","+str(v)+")") * eval("Ppers"+str(pNuevos[15])+"("+str(pTotales[15])+","+str(z-v-u-t-s-r-q-p-o-n-m-l-k-j-i)+")")

                                                        probability13 = probability13 + eval("Ppers"+str(pNuevos[13])+"("+str(pTotales[13])+","+str(u)+")") * probability14

                                                    probability12 = probability12 + eval("Ppers"+str(pNuevos[12])+"("+str(pTotales[12])+","+str(t)+")") * probability13
 
                                                probability11 = probability11 + eval("Ppers"+str(pNuevos[11])+"("+str(pTotales[11])+","+str(s)+")") * probability12

                                            probability10 = probability10 + eval("Ppers"+str(pNuevos[10])+"("+str(pTotales[10])+","+str(r)+")") * probability11

                                        probability9 = probability9 + eval("Ppers"+str(pNuevos[9])+"("+str(pTotales[9])+","+str(q)+")") * probability10

                                    probability8 = probability8 + eval("Ppers"+str(pNuevos[8])+"("+str(pTotales[8])+","+str(p)+")") * probability9

                                probability7 = probability7 + eval("Ppers"+str(pNuevos[7])+"("+str(pTotales[7])+","+str(o)+")") * probability8

                            probability6 = probability6 + eval("Ppers"+str(pNuevos[6])+"("+str(pTotales[6])+","+str(n)+")") * probability7

                        probability5 = probability5 + eval("Ppers"+str(pNuevos[5])+"("+str(pTotales[5])+","+str(m)+")") * probability6

                    probability4 = probability4 + eval("Ppers"+str(pNuevos[4])+"("+str(pTotales[4])+","+str(l)+")") * probability5

                probability3 += eval("Ppers"+str(pNuevos[3])  +  "("+str(pTotales[3])+","+str(k)+")") * probability4

            probability2 += eval("Ppers"+str(pNuevos[2])  +  "("+str(pTotales[2])+","+str(j)+")") * probability3

        probability1 += eval("Ppers"+str(pNuevos[1])  +  "("+str(pTotales[1])+","+str(i)+")") * probability2

    return probability1

print (str(Activate(700)))
```

Edit: Alright I think it would be helpful to explain a couple things:

-First of all, I was trying to find ways the code could run faster, as I'm aware the nested for loops are a performance hog. I was also hoping there would be a way to optimize so many factorial operations.

-Also, the P(A) function described in the g function represents the probability of an event happening, which is already in the code, in the first function from the top.

- There's also the function f in the formula, which is just a simplification of the function g for specific cases.
- The function f is the second function in the code, whereas g is the third function in the code.

I will try to find a way to simplify the multiple summations, and thanks for the tip of not using eval()!
I'm sorry again for not specifying the question more, and for that mess of code also.

Comment: What are you calculating? The definitions of 'P' and 'g' mutually reference each other with no base cases (and contain references to other unspecified variables), so a lot of information is missing here. Also, no one can/will debug your 15-deep-nested code. Write out the formula you're trying to calculate, a *small* example, your code for the small example, and what the problem seems to be.

Comment: When the number of possibilities is so big that the computational time become totally insane, the only solutions is generally to change the approach or the needs. There I do not think there is a magical algorithm that can speed up the computation to a reasonable time so I think you need to search for a better mathematical approach. Because solving the problem seems not easy, one solution may be to search for an approximation. https://mathoverflow.net and https://www.wolframalpha.com/ should help. Besides this, please try to never use `eval` (insanely slow & less readable & unsafe).

Comment: This is a beautiful piece of code (if you want to turn your laptop into a radiator), but what is the question exactly ?

Comment: I think that this is the first time that i have ever seen implementation of a 14 deep nested for loop.

Comment: Alright people, I tried clearing things up a bit, thanks a lot for your patience, seriously!

Answer (score 0):

I would expect to break it down with something like this:

```
def main():
    A = 0.5
    m = 10
    result = g(A, m)
    return


def sigma(k, m):
    ''' function to deal with the sum loop'''

    for k in range(10, m+1):
        # the bits in the formula
        pass

    return

def g(A, m):
    ''' function to deal with g '''
    k=10
    return 2 * sigma(k,m)



if __name__=='__main__':
    ''' This is executed when run from the command line '''
    main()
```

Or alternatively to do similar with classes.

I expect you also need a function for `p(A)` and one for factorials.